# Java feign.FeignException: status 400 reading SblConnectorService

Tags: java, feign

I have the following simple method.

```
public Response uploadProfilePicture(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile uploadFile, @RequestPart("file1") MultipartFile uploadFile1) throws EcException {
    User currentUser = authUserContext.getUser();
    ProfileImage profileImage = userManager.uploadProfilePicture(currentUser, uploadFile);
    ProfileImage profileImage = userManager.uploadProfilePicture(currentUser, uploadFile1);
    return httpApiResponse(profileImage);
}
```

In the above method

```
ProfileImage profileImage = userManager.uploadProfilePicture(currentUser, uploadFile);
```

Works fine  but

```
ProfileImage profileImage = userManager.uploadProfilePicture(currentUser, uploadFile1);
```

throws

> feign.FeignException: status 400 reading
>   CzrConnectorService#uploadFileE(String,String,LocalDate,String,MultipartFile)

exception. Both are doing the same method call do a call to a feign client. Only difference is
Working method call passes

> @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile uploadFile

but other one pass

> @RequestPart("file1") MultipartFile uploadFile1

The difference is only the Request param name "file" and "file1". I tested several times and feign client works only if the RequestPart name is "file".

Feign endpoint is as below.

```
@PostMapping(value = SBLEndpoints.SBL_S3_UPLOAD_FILE_E, consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    ResponseEntity<SBLFileUploadResponse> uploadFileE(@RequestParam("fileUniqueId") String fileUniqueId,
                                                     @RequestParam("filePath") String filePath,
                                                     @RequestParam(value = "expiryDate", required = false) LocalDate expiryDate,
                                                     @RequestParam("contentType") String contentType,
                                                     @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile uploadFile);
```

What is the cause of this scenario?